# How to switch name and surname in data frame so it is in the right column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks somewhat like this:

`specific_value      name    surname random_value
1              1      Luke  Skywalker            1
2              1      Luke  Skywalker            2
3              1 Skywalker       Luke            3
4              2      Leia     Organa            4
5              3       Han       Solo            5
6              2    Organa       Leia            6
7              1       Ben       Solo            7
8              5     Lando Calrissian            8`

```
structure(list(specific_value = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5), name = c("Luke", 
"Luke", "Skywalker", "Leia", "Han", "Organa", "Ben", "Lando"), 
    surname = c("Skywalker", "Skywalker", "Luke", "Organa", "Solo", 
    "Leia", "Solo", "Calrissian"), random_value = c(1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 6, 7, 8)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("specific_value", 
"name", "surname", "random_value"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

In it, some names are in the surname column and vice versa. 
What is the best way to find these kind of switched values and switch them? If there is no other way, the specific_value column can be of some help, but it is not necessary, that it is unique for different names/surnames.

Edit: The right order is the one that has more occurrences. In this example, Luke as a name, because it is in that column twice. If the occurrences are the same, you can't tell. But in general, the right order should always occur more often (the wrong one will be 1 in 13 or something similar).

Edit2: There are two more problems which I forgot to mention. First one is, that my data is more than 3mill rows long. The second one is, I need to rely also on specific_value, as there is a probability, that someones name is Skywalker and his surname is Luke. But this person differs from the other by his specific_value.

Comment: Question for u, how to determine which order is correct one ? like  Luke  Skywalker and Skywalker       Luke  , which one is correct

Comment: How will you know which is given name and surname?  For example,   If the name was Harrison Cooper,   what would you want?

Comment: @Wen I have edited the question with this info

Comment: Ties? what happens?

Comment: @CPak if there is a tie, it doesn't really matter, but it would be better, if it is the same as the first occurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using **`dplyr`**. First, we create a new name called `min_max`, which should be the same regardless of the `name`/`surname` ordering. Then we create `full_name_1` which is pasted together using the surname name ordering. Then we count by `full_name_1` and `min_max`. Finally, we create the new names by comparing the count to the max(count). If they match, the names stay the same, if not, they're swapped.

```
dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(min_max = paste0(max(c(name, surname)), 
                          ", ",
                          min(c(name, surname))),
         full_name_1 = paste0(surname, ", ", name)) %>%
  group_by(full_name_1, min_max) %>%
  mutate(count = n()) %>%
  group_by(min_max) %>%
  mutate(name_2 = ifelse(count == max(count),
                           name, surname),
         surname_2 = ifelse(count == max(count),
                          surname, name)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-min_max, -full_name_1, -count,
         -name, -surname)

#   specific_value random_value name_2  surname_2
#            <dbl>        <dbl>  <chr>      <chr>
# 1              1            1   Luke  Skywalker
# 2              1            2   Luke  Skywalker
# 3              1            3   Luke  Skywalker
# 4              2            4   Leia     Organa
# 5              3            5    Han       Solo
# 6              2            6 Organa       Leia
# 7              1            7    Ben       Solo
# 8              5            8  Lando Calrissian
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to achieve this with `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

df <- tribble(
        ~name,      ~surname, ~random_value,
       "Luke",   "Skywalker",            1L,
       "Luke",   "Skywalker",            2L,
  "Skywalker",        "Luke",            3L,
       "Leia",      "Organa",            4L,
        "Han",        "Solo",            5L,
     "Organa",        "Leia",            6L,
        "Ben",        "Solo",            7L,
      "Lando",  "Calrissian",            8L
  )
```

First create a unique ID for each person by combining their two names alphabetically (`unique_name`).

```r
df_with_id <- df %>%
  mutate(
    unique_name = map2_chr(name, surname, ~{
      str_sort(c(.x, .y)) %>% str_c(collapse = " ")
    })
  )
```

Then for each person, combine their first and last names, for each person (`unique_name`) count the occurrences of that ordering of of first/last names (`full_name`), then for each person keep the most commonly occurring full name (random if all equally common).

```r
names_xwalk <- df_with_id %>% 
  mutate(full_name = str_c(name, " ", surname)) %>% 
  count(unique_name, full_name) %>% 
  group_by(unique_name) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  separate(full_name, c("first_name", "last_name")) %>% 
  select(-n)
```

Now you have a reference table that you can merge back onto your original data. So just drop the original name columns, and merge the new most common ones back in.

```r
final <- df_with_id %>% 
  select(-name, -surname) %>% 
  left_join(names_xwalk, by = "unique_name") %>% 
  select(-unique_name)

final

#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   random_value first_name  last_name
#>          <int>      <chr>      <chr>
#> 1            1       Luke  Skywalker
#> 2            2       Luke  Skywalker
#> 3            3       Luke  Skywalker
#> 4            4       Leia     Organa
#> 5            5        Han       Solo
#> 6            6       Leia     Organa
#> 7            7        Ben       Solo
#> 8            8      Lando Calrissian
```

Comment: Would this work if the specific_value are specific for the same person, but not unique?

Comment: @Ravonrip What do you men by not unique? Are there cases where there are two different people that share the same value for `specific_value`? In that case this would not work. You could get around this by making a new column from `name` and `surname` that sorted alphabetically and then concatenated.

Comment: @Ravonrip I added the idea I described above so that now you don'y need the `specific_value` id column

Comment: Yes, I meant that. I sadly named it ambiguously. The `specific_value` is actually a birthdate.

Comment: I will try to implement this solution when I get the chance. If it is quicker than the one from bouncyball, I will accept it. Thank you.